# How to get a value from a Range? - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data in a table and depending on their sale I have to assign a cost:

[image: Cost Range]

For example, if have a sale of 200,000 my cost will be 61,298.

I have tried to make a measure to get this but with my current formula, I only get the Sum of all of the values of Cost.

```
Cost of Sale = CALCULATE(SUM('Cat_VEA0 Cost'[Cost]),
                   FILTER('Cat_VEA0 Cost',
                       [Sales] >= MIN('Cat_VEA0 Cost'[From]) &&
                       [Sales] < MAX('Cat_VEA0 Cost'[To])))
```

So I don't know, how to get the value of Cost, depending on which range of Sales it is each shop.

Comment: What is the formula for `[Sales]` and what visual(s) are you using it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAXX()` supposing you want to match only one row in `'Cat_VEA0 Cost'` and you want the row with the maximum price.

#### Solution

```
Cost of sale = MAXX(
    FILTER(
        'Cat_VEA0 Cost',
        AND(
            'Cat_VEA0 Cost'[From] <= SUM(Sheet2[Sales]),
            SUM(Sheet2[Sales]) < 'Cat_VEA0 Cost'[To]
        )
    ),
    [Cost]
)
```

### Explanation

Get the maximum `[Cost]` from all the rows that meet the condition:

```
MAXX(..., [Cost])
```

Set the condition to `[From]` `<=` `SUM([Sales])` `<=` `[To]`:

```
FILTER(
    'Cat_VEA0 Cost',
    AND(
        'Cat_VEA0 Cost'[From] <= SUM(Sheet2[Sales]),
        SUM(Sheet2[Sales]) < 'Cat_VEA0 Cost'[To]
    )
)
```